# 'Avenir' font renders differently on Chrome for Android/Desktop

Tags: android, google-chrome, fonts

I'm trying to design buttons using Avenir font.
Here are some screenshots from the following page : https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir/webfont_preview.html

On Chrome for Android, the text seems to be aligned on top :

[image: android sample] [image: android sample]

On Chrome for Desktop, it appears vertically centered (correct behavior when trying other fonts) :

[image: desktop sample][image: other desktop sample]

Is this a bug from the font or from the rendering engine ?
What is the formula to compute the size of the containing box (the blue one in colored samples) ?